# Converting a bytearray from a serial port to a float

Tags: python, parsing, serial-port, arrays

I am writing a python script that will communicate to a Fluke meter over a COM port.  I am able to receive the data but want to parse it into a usable float.  The code looks like this:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=1)

#Decalring some variables
FlukeID = b'ID\r'
FlukeQM = b'QM\r'

#Requesting the meters ID to verify connection on terminal
ser.writelines(FlukeID)
line = ser.readline()
print(line)

#Declaring variables for my while loop
thermdata = 0
t=1

ser.writelines(FlukeQM)
thermdata = ser.readline()

while(t < 5):
    ser.writelines(FlukeQM)
    #thermdata = (thermdata + ser.readline()) /2
    thermdata = ser.readline()
    print(thermdata)
    t+=1
```

The data returned by the device looks like this on the console:

***8.597E3,OHM,NORMAL,NONE*** ***INCORRECT***

***EDIT:*** The data actually appears like this over the terminal:
***b'0\r8.597E3,OHM,NORMAL,NONE\r'***

I just want to be able to use the numerical value at the beginning so I can do some calculations over time.  I also need to be able to use the scientific notion portion in my number as I will not know the range of my measurements before hand.  I know there must be a simple way to do this and would greatly appreciate any help.

On a side note, I would also like to be able to graph these values or place them into some kind of .csv file.  If you have any comments on where to look to learn how to do this also that would be great, but I am mostly concerned with the handling of the bytearray.

Comment: `float('8.597E3')` -> `8597.0`. Also if you can just write lines like `"8.597E3,OHM,NORMAL,NONE"` + newline to a file, and it'll be in csv format.

Comment: Well the CSV part seems pretty obvious now haha. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the question unutbu.  The information is definitely being stored as bytes.

Comment: @Menimitz: Ah, I see now -- you are talking about `bytes` objects. [bytearrays](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#bytearray) are something different.

Answer (score 2):

Use `split()` to break your string into the comma separated parts.  Then the first part is the string '8.597E3', which you convert using the `float()` function.

```
s = '8.597E3,OHM,NORMAL,NONE'.split(',')
value = float(s[0])
```

Comment: This won't work unless I first convert it to a string.  I can use .decode('utf-8') to accomplish this.  Not sure if that is the best way, but that is how I have done this before and it is all coming back to me.  At this point I would also need to trim off some extra items (See my edit above of what the byte array actually looks like) and am sure I can work this out now.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
def atof(text):
    try:
        return float(text)
    except ValueError:
        return text

thermdata = b'0\r8.597E3,OHM,NORMAL,NONE\r'
for line in thermdata.strip().split(b'\r'):
    print(list(map(atof, line.split(b','))))

# [0.0]
# [8597.0, b'OHM', b'NORMAL', b'NONE']
```